# How do I restore a default Mii Fighter?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When Mii Fighters are unlocked in World of Light, the game will provide default Miis that match the character select icons. However, while creating Mii Fighters with my friends, we accidentally deleted the default Mii Swordfighter.

How can I restore the default Mii Swordfighter after accidentally deleting it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "restore" a deleted Mii Fighter, but you can create one that matches the defaults.  If you create a new Mii Fighter, and leave all of the selections the default setting (e.g. don't change any of the costume settings or any of the move selections) you'll have the equivalent of the default generated Mii Fighter.  I can't remember which Mii template each fighter uses, but it is one of the default templates rather than one you would have to generate.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Mii's default appearance? Or does it need to use a pre-existing Mii?

Comment: You don't need to use a preexisting Mii.  When you create a Mii Fighter, it should give you a choice of which Mii you want to select.  Among them are a bunch of 'default' Miis - ones that you didn't make but just come with the system.  One of those are what are used by the Mii Fighters unlocked via World of Light.